# How to uninstall reportico in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I have already installed reportico in my laravel 5 project. Since I use another tools for reports, How can I uninstall reportico in my laravel app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `composer.json` and remove the reportico require line, then run `composer update`

Hope that helps.